# Python Google Cloud Function call from Flutter. Response is not valid JSON object

Tags: python, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and Flutter and I want to call a function from my flutter project. This GCF computes the Levenshtein distance between two strings and is implemented like:

```py
from flask import jsonify, abort
from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein_distance, ratio, editops as string_ops_needed

def json_abort(status_code, message):
    data = {
        'error': {
            'code': status_code,
            'message': message
        }
    }
    response = jsonify(data)
    response.status_code = status_code
    abort(response)

def word_distance(request, decoded_token = None):

    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    '''request_args = request.args'''

    if request_json and "candidate_string" in request_json and "correct_string" in request_json:
        candidate_string=request_json["candidate_string"]
        correct_string=request_json["correct_string"]

        distance=levenshtein_distance(candidate_string,correct_string)

        response = jsonify(distance=distance, status_code=200)
        return response
    else:
        json_abort(400, message="Missing params")
```

When I try to call it from flutter, with the following code Flutter returns
**Exception has occurred.**
PlatformException (PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {message: Response is not valid JSON object., details: null, code: INTERNAL}))

```dart
final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
        .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'word_distance')
          ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);

    dynamic result = await callable.call(
      <String, dynamic>{
        "candidate_string": candidateString,
        "correct_string": correctString
      },
    );
```

When I test the function in GCF with `{"candidate_string": "helo worlt", "correct_string": "hello world"}`

It returns the result `{"distance":2,"status_code":200}`

Any idea on why it happens and how to solve this issue? I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056727/google-cloud-functions-return-valid-json) but it does not show a specific example on how to proceed.

Comment: Are you able to get a proper response by manually `curl`-ing the endpoint for your function? Does your function allow unauthenticated invocations? Is there anything in the logs for your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a look at GCF log as suggested by Dustin Ingram, I found that my function was being accessed but the parameters and output where not ok. So after deeply checking this [example](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-functions/create-compatitle-cloud-function-for-firebase-with-python/) again, and taking into account [Google specs for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) I found out that it is necessary to return a 'data'/'error' json.

I changed my GCF to the following and now it returns the expected value.

```
from flask import jsonify, abort

from Levenshtein import distance as levenshtein_distance, ratio, editops as string_ops_needed

def word_distance(request):

    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Request>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>.
    """

    request_json = request.json.get('data')

    if "candidate_string" in request_json and "correct_string" in request_json:
        candidate_string=request_json["candidate_string"]
        correct_string=request_json["correct_string"]

        distance=levenshtein_distance(candidate_string,correct_string)

        return jsonify({
            'data': {
                'distance': distance
            }
        })
    else:
        data = {
            'error': {
                'code': 400,
                'message': 'Missing params'
            }
        }
        response = jsonify(data)
        response.status_code = 400
        return(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are calling the function with a Map argument which I think is causing the error because it can not get parsed into `JSON` properly.

Try using

```
<String, dynamic>{
        '"candidate_string"': '"$candidateString"',
        '"correct_string"': '"$correctString"'
      }
```

I have got this error many times when sending json data via `TCP` protocol and the above one worked for me, reason being, it can easily parsed into JSON

Comment: I tried this approach but it still retrieves the same error.